# Show (a,b) ~ R for any interval (a,b)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm working through Abbott's Understanding Analysis, which is also my first introduction to proofs.  I'd like to know if the following answer is sufficient, or if more work needs to be done.

Show (a, b) ~ R for any interval (a, b)

Proof:

Let f: ($\frac{-π}{2}$, $\frac{π}{2}$) -> R be given by f(x) = tan(x)
We can see from the graph of f(x) that it is bijective.

Let g: (a, b) -> ($\frac{-π}{2}$, $\frac{π}{2}$) be given by:
$$g(x) = \frac{πx}{(b-a)} - \frac{π(a+b)}{2(b-a)}$$
Since g(x) is a linear function that maps each element of (a, b) to ($\frac{-π}{2}$, $\frac{π}{2}$), then it is therefore bijective.

Let h: (a, b) -> R be given by h(x) = f(g(x))
Since h(x) is a composite of two bijective functions, it is therefore bijective

=> (a, b) ~ R

My question is whether or not I need to do any more work to show that f, g, and h are bijective.

Comment: I personally would not use the graph of $f$ as justification for being bijective. It would be worth putting in the proper details to show bijectivity, for me. But for $g$ and $h$, I think what you have is great.

Comment: You should really define your notation. I, for one, have never seen "$\sim$" for "is in bijection with".

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct, but you can add a proof of the fact that $\tan|_{\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)}$ is bijective. This follows from the fact that$$\lim_{x\to\pm\frac\pi2}\tan x=\pm\infty,$$that the tangent function is continuous and that its restriction to $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ is strictly increasing.

Answer (score 1):

For $g$, it is linear but for $f$, to prove it is bijective, you prove that it is continuous and stricly monotonic.

here is an other function 
$$h : (a,b) \rightarrow \Bbb R$$
$$x \mapsto \ln(\frac{b-x}{x-a})$$